# Tuple case mapping don't work with generic Array[T] in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, pattern-matching, manifest, implicit

I don't understand why the compiler cannot understand the `case` instruction mapping on tuple when i try to use with generics `Array[T]`.

```
class Variable[T](val p: Prototype[T], val value: T)

class Prototype[T](val name: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T])

  // Columns to variable converter
implicit def columns2Variables[T](columns:Array[(String,Array[T])]): Iterable[Variable[Array[T]]] = {
    columns.map{
      case(name,value) =>
      new Variable[Array[T]](new Prototype[Array[T]](name), value)
     }.toIterable
  }
```

Error say :

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2)
required: fr.geocite.simExplorator.data.Variable[Array[T]]
case(name,value) =>
```

Comment: if one deletes the implicit keyword before the method and adds an implicit Manifest to the method the code compiles fine. I would say this looks like a bug.

Comment: I think you do need to pass a manifest for T to the method (so it can pass it over to new Prototype), but I think there is a bug too. It compiles for me changing the signature: `implicit def columns2Variables[T : Manifest](columns:Array[(String,Array[T])]) = { ...` note the Manifest and the fact I've removed the type for the return value (it compiles and the type is inferred to the one you had specified... go figure...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also not sure about the wording of the error, but first of all, you will need the manifest for `T` because it is required for constructing `new Prototype[Array[T]]` (the array manifest can be automatically generated if a manifest for its type parameter is in scope).

Is there any reason you absolutely need arrays? They come with the irregularity of Java's type system, they are mutable, and they offer very little advantage over for example `Vector`. Lastly, and that's probably why carry around the manifests, unlike arrays standard collections do not require manifests for construction.

```
class Variable[T](val p: Prototype[T], val value: T)
class Prototype[T](val name: String)

implicit def cols2v[T](cols: Vector[(String,Vector[T])]): Vector[Variable[Vector[T]]] =
  cols.map {
    case (name, value) => new Variable(new Prototype(name), value)
  }
```